# Join two entries rows ( Start time and End time) as a single row in Talend

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, t-sql, talend

I have Data coming from a MS SQL Database, it is concerning the the working hours of employees.

The problem is that, the start time and the end time are stored as 2 different entries, so when the employee comes, he scans his badge and this is considered arrival time, and when he leaves, he scans his badge again and this is considered departure time.
There is one column that helps to make the difference between the start and the end time (CodeNr column : B1 = StartTime, B2 = EndTime)

so this is how my Table looks like

[image]

Now i need this data as a single entry, in Talend oder from the Database,

so that should looks like

[image]

What to use in order to achieve this please (specially in Talend and when to complicate than in MS SQL)?

Comment: Why don't you create the query in SQL Server ? I think it's better

Comment: Even in SQL server , I'm in a bit of trouble, I don't know whether to do an inner join or something else... if you have an idea :)

Comment: Please share your tables design and data

Comment: all my fields are integer , except the CodeNr which is a Char , a data sample is like on the below picture. for creating the table, here is a request 

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeWorkLoad](
 [EmployeeNr] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Year] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Month] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Day] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Hour] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Minute] [int] NOT NULL,
 [CodeNr] [char](2) NULL,)`

Comment: For the data sample, the request is 

 `
Insert into [EmployeeWorkLoad]  ( [EmployeeNr],[Year],[Month] ,[Day],[Hour], [Minute] ,[CodeNr])
 Values (1,2020,1,4,8,30,'B1'),
  (1,2020,1,4,16,45,'B2'),
 (1,2020,1,6,8,15,'B1'),
 (1,2020,1,6,16,45,'B2'),
 (2,2020,3,2,8,10,'B1'),
 (2,2020,3,2,16,5,'B1');
 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE EmployeeWorkLoad(
> EmployeeNr bigint,
> Year int,
> Month int,
> Day int,
> Hour int,
> Minute int,
> CodeNr char(2)
> )
>
>
> Insert into [EmployeeWorkLoad] ( [EmployeeNr],[Year],[Month] ,[Day],[Hour], [Minute] ,[CodeNr]) Values (1,2020,1,4,8,30,'B1'), 
> (1,2020,1,4,16,45,'B2'), 
> (1,2020,1,6,8,15,'B1'), 
> (1,2020,1,6,16,45,'B2'),
> (2,2020,3,2,8,10,'B1'), 
> (2,2020,3,2,16,5,'B2')
>   
>   
> GO
> ```

6 rows affected

> 

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (
> select EmployeeNr,Year,Month,Day,
>
> MAX(CASE WHEN CodeNr='B1' THEN Hour  END) AS StartHour,
> MAX(CASE WHEN CodeNr = 'B1' THEN Minute END) AS StartMinute,
> MAX(CASE WHEN CodeNr = 'B2' THEN Hour END) AS EndHour,
> MAX(CASE WHEN CodeNr = 'B2' THEN Minute END) AS EndMinute
>
> from EmployeeWorkLoad
> group by EmployeeNr,Year,Month,Day )
>
> SELECT * , ABS(EndHour-StartHour) AS DutationHour
> ,ABS(IIF(EndMinute <StartMinute, EndMinute+60, EndMinute)- StartMinute) AS DurationMinute
> FROM
> CTE
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> EmployeeNr | Year | Month | Day | StartHour | StartMinute | EndHour | EndMinute | DutationHour | DurationMinute
> ---------: | ---: | ----: | --: | --------: | ----------: | ------: | --------: | -----------: | -------------:
>          1 | 2020 |     1 |   4 |         8 |          30 |      16 |        45 |            8 |             15
>          1 | 2020 |     1 |   6 |         8 |          15 |      16 |        45 |            8 |             30
>          2 | 2020 |     3 |   2 |         8 |          10 |      16 |         5 |            8 |             55
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c9fb407cbe975bc09202dc4e5462602)*

Comment: Thanks Amira, it works!

Just for someonelse who might want to apply this and is using MS SQL Server, i don t know why but the `(IIF(EndMinute <StartMinute, EndMinute+60, EndMinute)- StartMinute)` generates this error **Incorrect syntax near '<' ** so rather than this i used a 

` CASE   
      WHEN EndMinute < StartMinute THEN EndMinute+60 - StartMinute  
      ELSE EndMinute - StartMinute END AS DurationMinute  `

Comment: @Reims IIF is a SQL2012 feature replace your IIF with a CASE ( Which is what SQL 2012 would do anyway )